# How can I align a div element in existing content

Tags: css

**I will explain with a little example here:**

I have html page with some content already, and without modifying that content I want to insert ***some message*** (say inserting an image) in middle of the already existing content by leaving the div at top.

**Take look at this picture, which is before doing some css work:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhJbx.png

**Description:** Image inserted in the content at the top of the content with div is at the top

**And now after applying the css, I want to place some where in between the content, like this:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/67YFf.png

**Description:** Image inserted with css aligned in middle of the content but div is at the top

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myimg">
    <img src=http://s14.postimg.org/miss2r3xt/html_css.jpg />
</div>
<p>Some paragraph    </p>

<strong>What is HTML?</strong>

<strong>What is CSS?</strong>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myimg {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is link for a simple example, that I am trying to modify at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjCfp/1/).

Let me know if you guys can help!!!

Comment: I don't think this can be done only with CSS (or without seriously hacking the box model...). Maybe I'm wrong but I think you have to move your `<img />` tag instead

Comment: So you want to move the image inside the div but not the div? Why?

Comment: Actually in my website I already have all the content of the posts stored in database, and now I want to insert a simple message at a particular place of the post without modifying the original content in the database.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with css. Would Jquery be an option?

Comment: Also I may modify the inserted content on regular basis, so that's why I don't want to insert this into database. And want to do it with my templates and css!!!

Comment: Also, how do you identify this *place* if the markup can alter?

Comment: @Liam, Yes. But the div should scroll along with the content of the page!!!

Comment: I have predefined positions in alignment of the posts, so if I can do this, then I can integrate.

Comment: To position the image, you must know the height of the content in the first paragraph, and also position the second paragraph under the new location for the image. With dynamic content from a database, this will not be possible using only CSS. But it is quite simple to move the image into the content with jQuery.

Comment: Is it with jQuery, we can do it even if the content is randomly placed (aligned) as opposed to have some fixed height ?

Answer (score 2):

For adding some elements with CSS, take a look at [:after](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) et [:before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp).

For example, you can add this line to your css

```
strong:before{ 
    content:url('http://s14.postimg.org/miss2r3xt/html_css.jpg'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you accept jQuery solution, this would place the image after the first paragraph in the content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var theImg = $('.myimg').remove(); 
    $('p').first().after(theImg);
});
```

If you have a marker in your content, then use that marker instead of `$('p').first()`.

Your fidlle, updated with this approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjCfp/9/

Answer (score 1):

Try out below css to position the image with out modifying the html content:

```
.myimg {
margin-top: 100px;
}
div.myimg + p {
 position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
    left: 0px;


}
```

Have a look at the working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjCfp/7/)

Comment: This only works if the text is 100px in height, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjCfp/10/. The OP says this will alter.